# Looking for good examples/explanations of maximum likelihood estimators for discrete random variables

Tags: undergraduate-education, examples, statistics

The title basically says it all. I need to prepare material for a whole classroom of elementary statistics students, so if anyone wants to help me out in the name of math education, that'd be great!

Comment: Is this for an undergraduate class?

Comment: Yes sir indeed it is

Comment: Get a textbook, follow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be helpful:

> Pishro-Nik, Hossein. *Introduction to probability, statistics, and random processes.* (2016). [Open access textbook](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/).

[image]

[Section 8.2.3](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_2_3_max_likelihood_estimation.php): Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

His exposition includes five examples, several discrete, with solutions.

> "I have a bag that contains 3 balls. Each ball is either red or blue." Etc.